# custom post type and archive widget

Tags: wordpress

I create my own template with forge and create several custom type and everything work fine.
The problem is that when I try to use the widgets like Archive or search I obtain a

```
No posts found.
```

any idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the Archive widget try what it says [here].[1](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/100005/including-a-custom-post-type-in-the-archives-widget)

And with the Search widget try adding this to your functions.php

```
function filter_search($query) {
    if ($query->is_search) {
    $query->set('post_type', array('post', 'folio'));
    };
    return $query;
};
add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'filter_search');
```

Where it says "array('post', 'folio'));" change folio or add the names of your custom post types.